# Why does chrome render fonts so brightly?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

The image below is a combination of three screenshots of the same page/paragraph: The first from Chrome, the Second from IE, and the third from Firefox.

The color is black (`#000`), `font-family` is `Helvetica` and `font-size` is `12px`.

As we can see, the font in Chrome doesn't look very black. It even look quite pale. While in IE, the font is rendered in a much darker black, and easier to read. In Firefox it's much better than Chrome but still not as black as IE.

Does anybody know what makes this difference, and if there is a workaround for this problem (that doesn't involve crazy CSS hacks)?

Thanks.

[image: same font, three different browsers]

Comment: Open `chrome://flags` and post whether "Disable DirectWrite" is enabled or disabled.

Comment: It's disabled. I tried with both options though and it looks the same.

Comment: @Yair did you restart the browser after switching directWrite?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of how browsers render websites, this should fix it:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
```

Edit: I think it also fixes how text looks on OSX

Comment: Thanks, but my eyes couldn't see a difference

Answer (score 0):

I see the exact same problem when testing web fonts on my own website. All web fonts look thinner in Chrome than they do in other browsers; this even renders some fonts, which otherwise would look nicely balanced, practically useless.

One CSS property I found that helps is:

```
-webkit-text-stroke
```

But it's not a perfect fix, and it's invalid CSS.

It's 2016 now, and the problem is still there. I can't really say I understand why they're not fixing it. (And no, a fix should never imply having to change browser settings yourself.)

It seems to be a relatively underreported problem as well, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I made this javascript to fix Chrome font rendering problem (too thin!) on my websites.

**Script details:** the script adds a colored and semi-trasparent text shadow to elements which contain text.

The color of the shadow is the same of the one of the text to which it is applied.

The opacity of the shadow is inversely proportional to luminosity of the text color: for example, for #FFFFFF it is set to 0% while for #000000 it becomes 70% (174 in decimal, where the max is 255).

```js
function FixChromeFonts() { // v1.00
    var Max_Darkness=174 // 0-255
    var AllElem=document.querySelectorAll(':not(script):not(style):not(area):not(base):not(br):not(col):not(embed):not(hr):not(img):not(input):not(keygen):not(link):not(meta):not(param):not(source):not(track):not(wbr):not(table):not(tbody):not(tr):not(ul)')
    for (var i=0;i<AllElem.length;i++) {
        for (var j=0;j<AllElem[i].childNodes.length;j++) { // cycle through element nodes
            if (AllElem[i].childNodes[j].nodeType===3 && AllElem[i].childNodes[j].textContent.trim().length>0) { // is it a text node?
                var Col=window.getComputedStyle(AllElem[i]).getPropertyValue('color').replace(/[^\d,]/g,'').split(',') // text color array (R/G/B)
                var Lum=Math.round(0.2126*Col[0]+0.7152*Col[1]+0.0722*Col[2]) // luminosity
                var Opa=parseFloat(Max_Darkness*(255-Lum)/65025).toFixed(1) // opacity between 0 and 1
                AllElem[i].style.setProperty('text-shadow','0 0 0 rgba('+Col[0]+','+Col[1]+','+Col[2]+','+Opa+')','important') // set text shadow with alpha
                break
            }
        }   
    }
}

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome/") != -1) window.onload=FixChromeFonts() // runs only after page has loaded in Chrome browser
```

```css
BODY {
  font-family:arial
}

.bigger {
  font-size:130%
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
This is a text
<div> <!-- text-shadow won't be applied to this div because it does not contain text nodes -->
  <div class=bigger>
    and this is another text
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```